# Заказать В или НА маркетплейсе?

Tags: предлоги, заимствования, латиница-кириллица

Скажите, пожалуйста, какой предлог правильнее выбрать? Заказать НА маркетплейсе или В маркетплейсе? Например, заказать На Ozon или В Ozon?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (11.07.2023)**

"Грамота.ру" ответила так (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310673)):

> «Правильного» и «неправильного» употребления предлога в таких сочетаниях сейчас нет: предлоги конкурируют, норма формируется на наших глазах, кодификация в словарях отсутствует. Вариант с предлогом *на* поддерживается конструкциями *на сайте*, *на (интернет-)площадке*, выбор предлога *в* может подкрепляться конструкцией *в (интернет-)магазине*. Можно рекомендовать для нейтрального употребления вариант *в интернет-магазине Ozon*. При передаче на письме обиходного разговорного употребления: *на Озоне*.

Comment: "На", потому что рынок (в переводе).

Comment: @oleedd по такой логике "Купить в яндекс-маркете", потому что магазин в переводе. На деле тут вопрос устоявшихся предпочтений. Почему они такие устоялись. Ну фишки предлога на перевесили фичи предлога в. Изначально многое тянется из купить на сайте, на ебее, итп

Comment: @user190920 Нет, market — это рынок.

Comment: Маркет это и рынок и магазин. Более того, на сайте яндекса написано интернет-магазин яндекс-маркет. Но дело не в переводе, перевод в лучшем случае может быть лишь одним из факторов исторического выбора.

Comment: @user190920 Вот самый авторитетный словарь: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/словарь/англо-русский/market Там только прямые значения, а не весь сброд (синонимы, варианты для замены). Магазин — это shop, store.

Comment: @oleedd магазин - это стор, от сторэдж - склад. Шоп - это лавка, типа лавка ремесленника, где он что-то делает.

Answer (score 3):

**Я не являюсь филологом или экспертом в области русского языка**, но, на мой взгляд, стоит руководствоваться следующими принципами:

1. Присутствует ли это слово с примерами использования в известных, заслуживших доверие словарях?
2. Если нет, то есть ли правило, которое можно применить к данному случаю?
3. Если нет, то какой вариант является более распространённым?

Итак, по пунктам:

1. С ходу искомое слово с примерами в словарях не находится (http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81&all=x).
2. Общего правила, определяющего употребление "в" и "на", скорее всего, не существует (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=275639).
3. Сравнение частоты запросов по Гуглу: вариант "купить в маркетплейсе" практически отсутствует (https://trends.google.ru/trends/explore?date=now%207-d&geo=RU&q=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B5&hl=ru). Вариант "купить на маркетплейсе" также почти отсутствует (https://trends.google.ru/trends/explore?date=now%207-d&geo=RU&q=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B5&hl=ru).
   Варианты "купить в Ozon" и "купить на Ozon" идут удивительно (для меня) близко, но в целом видно явное преобладание второго (https://trends.google.ru/trends/explore?date=now%207-d&geo=RU&q=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20Ozon,%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20Ozon&hl=ru).

Вообще, я считаю пример "Купить в/на Ozon" несколько некорректным, так как тут мы покупаем не в/на маркетплейсе, а именно **В** конкретной **компании**. Естественно, мы не можем что-то купить "на компании", это звучит просто чудовищно.

*(дальше начинаются мои дремучие домыслы)*

"Маркетплейс" - это, согласно дословному переводу, "рыночное место", "рынок". Очевидно, что товары мы покупаем НА рынке, а не В рынке. Если в качестве примера взять не "Озон", а "Яндекс.Маркет", то предпочтения пользователей становятся очевидными: строго **НА** Яндекс.Маркете, и никак иначе (https://trends.google.ru/trends/explore?date=now%207-d&geo=RU&q=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81.%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5,%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81.%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5&hl=ru).

В сухом остатке:

1. Я бы однозначно выбрал вариант "Заказать на маркетплейсе".
2. Что делать с "Озоном" - вопрос совершенно другой, так как тут смешивается название компании и неявно подразумеваемое Вами, но совершенно не читателем (мной, например) слово "маркетплейс". На мой скромный взгляд, совершенно удачно и непротиворечиво смотрелся бы вариант "Заказать на маркетплейсе "Ozon"" (хотя я понимаю, что использовать такую длинную конструкцию может быть сложно).

Ну и ещё раз упомяну, что **я не являюсь филологом или экспертом в области русского языка**, и всё написанное мной выше может являться грубой ошибкой и не соответствовать великим нормам и правилам нашего великого и могучего. Тут уж решайте сами)

Доброго дня!

Comment: Если заказывать в магазине Озон, то в Озоне. Если заказывать сайте Озона, то на Озоне. И так и так правильно.

Comment: @Василий Надо что-то одно выбрать. "На" в таких случаях используют.

Answer (score 1):

Интернет-маркет - это "торговая площадка", место где магазины демонстрируют каточки внешнего вида товара, дают описание, то есть всячески рекламируют и ставят цену. Купить товар в интернет-маркете вы не можете, просто потому что это не магазин(от арабского слова склад), вы отправляете запрос, делая заказ, а потом осуществляется покупка в магазине, причем без возможности выбора вами конкретного экземпляра - вам привозят что-то в пакете, открываете, а там 50/50, что б/у). Претензии по содержимому вы будете предъявлять продавцу, а не маркет-плейсу. Поэтому на Озоне-, на Вайлдберрисе-, на Яндекс-маркете.

Если маркет это рынок - то вы покупаете на рынке в павильоне номер 1 у продавца фирмы "ААА".

Интернет-магазины скорее всего имеют иной юр статус и в случае чего именно они несут ответственность за брак и тд.